# Visual Studio References, output dll

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reference, visual-studio-2013, firebird2.5

I would like to have a dll copy to bin/debug | bin/release folder on build of the executing application from a reference thats inside another reference.

For exmple lets assume I have the following two projects:

- UserInterface
- DataAccessLayer

In my DataAccessLayer project I have a referece to my DataProvider in my case **FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient**.

I know that I can set that the property "Copy Local" of the reference to true, but this will only output the DLL in the DataAccessLayer/bin/debug Folder, I would like to have tell it to output into the UserInterface bin/debug folder without giving the project a reference to this .NET Data Provider.
(I have already done it and did set Copy Local to true and can see that its successfully outputted to my DAL but its not in my UI)

How can I achieve this?

(I know its possible because I can see it happening with Entity Framework DLL, its only referenced to DataAccessLayer but outputs to my executing application, cannot tell the difference between those 2 references)

You may ask why, because Entity Framework needs the DLL of the provider its working with in the output.

Comment: Files and related dependencies are copied to the output directory by default. I would not go by EF references unless you also rely on the GAC. Somehow, you appear to have gone off the reservation.  Are you following best practices?  From the question its unclear how the projects are structured.  Are they part of one solution?  Is the solution at a higher level directory than all the related projects? Do you have a circular reference?    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817675.aspx#tdlg_ch4_ReferencingAssemblies

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey bestpractice: I guess so... one solution: Yes, 1 Solution (actually 3 projects, UI -> BL -> DAL | -> = references) higher level: solution file in level higher, since the projects are in different folders, like its default circular reference: ehm no.. 
everything is working fine in the application as long as I reference my .NET Data Provider directly to the UI and specify the Copy Local there to true, but why should the UI reference to the Data Provider DLL, makes no sense so I wanted to delete it and EF complained about not finding the provider, so how can I output it?

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey files and related ... : I can see it working with the DAL/bin/debug folder works create but it doesn't get outputted to the UI/bin/debug and that's where I (entity framework) needs it.